# How to generate Laravel Reset Password Token in Slim

Tags: php, laravel, slim, reset-password

I am developing `forgot` API in `SLIM` framework, But Web Application is developed in `Laravel 5.2`. So I have to generate `Reset Password Token` using same method as in `Laravel 5.2`. So I can send `Reset Password Link`, which will be used by `Laravel 5.2` on Web Application.

Any Idea, How can I do it.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't. Make an API call to your Laravel app and ask for a token there.

Comment: But, I have to send an email with  reset password link, which work for laravel.